# How to get python reference for a menu?

Tags: python, interface

I would like to make hotkey for this list

[image]

like this

[image]

what I should do?

Comment: Your first image is not showing up.

Answer (score 2):

1. Switch to *Scripting* screen
2. <kbd>RMB</kbd> on *Brush* and click *Edit Source*
3. Cursor will be located in this line: `layout.menu("VIEW3D_MT_brush")`
4. Search for `VIEW3D_MT_brush` in the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, you may need to enable *Wrap*)
5. You will find the `class VIEW3D_MT_brush(Menu): ...`
6. Scroll down a bit and locate `Curve Presets`, the code line is
   `layout.operator_menu_enum("brush.curve_preset", "shape", text="Curve Preset")`

As you can see, there's actually no menu, but an enum property that is displayed like a menu.

Thus, you can't use `bpy.ops.wm.call_menu()`. If you use [UILayout.operator_enum()](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.operator_enum) in the draw function for [WindowManager.popup_menu()](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.popup_menu) and wrap that call in an operator, it is possible to show the presets like a menu:

```
import bpy


def draw_func(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator_enum("brush.curve_preset", "shape")


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = bpy.context.window_manager
        wm.popup_menu(draw_func, title="Curve Preset")
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

How to set up keymaps is covered here, if you want to let the script do that itself:
 [Addon Tutorial #Keymaps](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/info_tutorial_addon.html#keymap) (you should make your script an addon in order to use keymaps)